# Modernizr complete function

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I start using Modernizr this days and I cant understand something. I have this code:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.generatedcontent,
    nope:['resources/js/selectivizr-min.js','style2.css'],
    complete: function() {}
});
```

And as you can see, i have this empty function on 'complete'. Without it, modernizr just do not apply selectivizr and style2.css to the page. Can someone give me an explanation why this happen or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.